# What is "import this, that, other, stuff" doing?

Tags: python

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import this, that, other, stuff
class SomeObject(object):
    pass

def some_function(*args,**kwargs):
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print( "This only executes when %s is executed rather than imported" % __file__)
```

**What is the above code doing? 
I'm getting the output as follows**

```
The Zen of Python, by Tim Peters

Beautiful is better than ugly.
Explicit is better than implicit.
Simple is better than complex.
Complex is better than complicated.
Flat is better than nested.
Sparse is better than dense.
Readability counts.
Special cases aren't special enough to break the rules.
Although practicality beats purity.
Errors should never pass silently.
Unless explicitly silenced.
In the face of ambiguity, refuse the temptation to guess.
There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.
Although that way may not be obvious at first unless you're Dutch.
Now is better than never.
Although never is often better than *right* now.
If the implementation is hard to explain, it's a bad idea.
If the implementation is easy to explain, it may be a good idea.
Namespaces are one honking great idea -- let's do more of those!
```

**I'm new to python but very curious to know. Please help me out.**

Comment: That is a hidden easter egg in Python, it is the text you get if you do `import this`.

Comment: If you don't actually have other modules named this.py, that.py, other.py and stuff.py, it seems you just copied non-working example code. It's not supposed to work exactly like that.

Answer (score 5):

Try to do the following:

```
import this
```

This line alone will make the interpreter output *The Zen of Python*

Answer (score 1):

```
import this
```

gives you the [*Zen of Python*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) by Tim Peters.  Since it is an import regardless of how your file is executed (directly or by import), your `if __name__ == '__main__':` block is incorrect in its `print()` call.  Your code will also throw an error unless you have `that.py`, `other.py`, and `stuff.py` on your computer, but whether you execute it directly or import it, the outcome will be the same.  Those modules (`that`, `other`, and `stuff`) aren't easter eggs :)

Answer (score 0):

if in python interpreter You do following: 1) help() 2) modules - You see a list of modules, "this" is one in a list; just type "this" (without quotes) - it contains ZEN of Python that's what You get in Your output here; lone import this would give You same output. But it is a place where to check what's in python modules, type any listed module name and see. The code is just a bear example.

Answer (score 0):

Despite the poem, it's a print function encoded in `this.py` like this way:

```
$ touch test.py
$ echo "print('Zen of Python')" > test.py
$ python -c "import test"
Zen of Python
```